# Is there a way to set the Powerpoint Slide Sorter Zoom above 100%?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In the PowerPoint slider sorter view, is there a way to set the zoom level larger than 100%? On PowerPoint for Mac this slider goes to much higher values, essentially allowing zoom all the way in to a single slide, but on the Windows version (depending on screen resolution and slide dimensions) the maximum zoom is often several slides wide.

Evidently it's possible to [achieve a similar affect by changing the page size](https://blogs.oracle.com/smuenchadf/entry/how_to_get_the_powerpoint_slid), but is there some sort of preferences hack that will change the maximum value of this slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in Slide Sorter View, vba will not let that get past 100, but in Office 2010, the slider control at the bottom right [image: slider control] will allow you to go to 200%

Comment: Sean, could you expand your answer to explain to the OP how they can use this command in Powerpoint.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Good to know. I assume like many other corporations we have not yet upgraded to Office 2010. I was hoping for a hack where I could edit some obscure settings file and change the maximum value of that slider.